# onPostExecute callback not calling invalidateOptionsMenu

Tags: android

I have a Activity in which when i click on refresh action bar icon it starts an async task. I have callbacks of async task in mainactity. in preexecute i am displaying progressbar on action bar and in postexecute i am displaying back refresh item. But when there is screen rotation after async task is started, onpostexecute runs but it is not calling invalidate options menu.

please help me out.

here is my MainActivity:

```html
package in.cdac.enbee;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RefreshTask.TaskCallbacks {

 // Our created menu to use
    private Menu mymenu;
 volatile static boolean isrefreshing=false;
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     Log.d("Debug", "OncreateOptionsMenu");
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        
        // We should save our menu so we can use it to reset our updater.
        mymenu = menu;
        
        if(isrefreshing) {
          menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setActionView(R.layout.action_progressbar);
  } else {
   menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setActionView(null);;
  }
        return true;
    }
    
   
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
     
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_refresh:
         // Do animation start
            new RefreshTask(this).execute();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
         return true;
        }
        
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     //Log.d("Debug", "OnSave");
     //Always call superclass first
     super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
     // Restore value of members from saved state
        //savedInstanceState.putBoolean("isRefreshing", isrefreshing);
        
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     //Log.d("Debug", "OnRestore");
     // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore value of members from saved state
         //isrefreshing = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isRefreshing");
        } else {
            // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
         //isrefreshing = false;
        }
           
    }   
    
 @Override
 public void onPreExecute() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  isrefreshing = true;
  invalidateOptionsMenu();
 }


 @Override
 public void onCancelled() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  isrefreshing = false;
  invalidateOptionsMenu();
 }


 @Override
 public void onPostExecute(Boolean done) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     isrefreshing = false;
  
  if(done) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Done refreshing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } else {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Downloading Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
  invalidateOptionsMenu();
 }
    
}
```

and my async task:

```html
package in.cdac.enbee;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class RefreshTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
  
    /**
  * 
  */
    
    static interface TaskCallbacks {
  void onPreExecute();
  void onCancelled();
  void onPostExecute(Boolean done);
 }
    
    private TaskCallbacks mCallbacks;
      
    public RefreshTask(TaskCallbacks mCallbacks) {
  this.mCallbacks = mCallbacks;
 }
    
    @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
  mCallbacks.onPreExecute();
  
 }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
      if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onCancelled();
      }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... nope) {
        try {
            // Set a time to simulate a long update process.
            Thread.sleep(4000);
             
            return true;
             
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
     
    
    @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Boolean done) {
  if (mCallbacks != null) {
   mCallbacks.onPostExecute(done);
  }
 }

}
```

and my layout file for progressbar:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/progressBar"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ProgressBar>
```

Thank you.

Comment: It seems like part of your code is missing.

Comment: @Okas Can you tell me which part of code?

Comment: Sorry, i misread your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your Acitvity object to AsyncTask. This approach does not work. Basically android system can destroy and later recreate your activity at any time (one example is when orientation changes) and you have to be prepared for this situation.

What you are seeing now is that your code is being called but it uses old activity, not the one created after orientation change, so your code has no effect.

Comment: So what do you suggest that i should do?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the proper way or not, but I did have a little workaround and it works.

I am creating an reference to RefreshTask Async task in mainactivity. Initially making it null.

```html
static RefreshTask rt=null;
```

then added a method in async task class.

```html
public void updateobject(TaskCallbacks mCallbacks) {
     this.mCallbacks = mCallbacks;
    }
```

and in mainactivity, in onRestoreInstanceState, calling that method.

```html
@Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     //Log.d("Debug", "OnRestore");
     // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        if(rt != null) {
         rt.updateobject(this);
        }
           
    }
```

Please let me know what you think.
Also, suggest me an alternative way of doing it.